# Word for people of a country who tend to embrace division and sectarian and ethnic profiling?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe people of a country who tend to embrace division and sectarian and ethnic profiling rather than fighting it? I need a word to describe the people of a country who wouldn't put an effort to fight or fix the issues that have been splitting them.

Comment: I need it for a research paper. It is mentioned in an article written in Afrikaans..

Comment: Look up the noun form of 'sectarian'.

Comment: So, you're looking for a word halfway in between *status quo* and *isolationist*, which also encompasses the phrase IDGAF ? *American* ? ;p

Comment: no actually.. but you mentioned in your comment "isolationist" which is derived from isolation, i wonder if there is a similar word derived from "division"

Answer (score 1):

[***Segregated***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/segregate) comes to mind.

> Separate or divide along racial, sexual, or religious lines.
>   *‘blacks were segregated in churches, schools, and colleges’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/segregate

Answer (score 0):

MW has this definition of race-baiting.  Race-baiter is the noun. Simple Definition of race–baiting
: the unfair use of statements about race to try to influence the actions or attitudes of a particular group of people